# 90 days range using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

is there a way in SQL server that i can count the items 90 days prior to the inception date and the items 90 days after the inception date. Example:

```
select
site,
count(*)
from mytable
where date >=10/1/2009' 
and date <'12/30/2009'
group by site
```

---

```
90 days before - after inception date.
prior to inception date = 7/3/2009.
inception date = 10/1/2009.
after inception date = 12/29/2009.
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Is the inception date always hard-coded?  Why not just change your date range to `>='7/1/2009'`?

Comment: the inception date are varied.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.site,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -90, '2009-10-01') AND DATEADD(ss, -1, '2009-10-01') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numPrior,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 1, '2009-10-01') AND DATEADD(dd, 91, '2009-10-01') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numPost
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.site
```

Tweak the [DATEADD function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and inception date as you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267(SQL.80).aspx